# list active directory User Display Name, OU and last password change date using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need the powershell script to list AD user names, OU they belonged to and last password change time/date using powershell or Quest ad shell.
I have seen many times the scrips to list the users in a particular OU but haven't found anything to list the users and OUs at the same time.
So the output I am looking for is:
User Full name1,  OU name1, Last password reset date1
User Full name2,  OU name2, Last password reset date2
User Full name3,  OU name3, Last password reset date3
.
.
.

Thank you.

Comment: We'll help you write one if you're willing to put forth the effort to learn the language and try to figure it out.  We're not really here to help you find scripts made to order.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple to build a script but to point you in the right direction the AD attributes you want to search for are: CN,distinguishedName,pwdLastSet.  Get-QADuser will return password  last set in date time format get-aduser will return it in a binary value